# Why is Sqlite CREATE QUESTION function not working?

Tags: sqlite

[Whenever I try to create a table the text stays as a string, im I doing something wrong?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GhSA.png)

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Hi, here are some guidelines for your answer: Please **DO NOT** post your code as an image, post is as a text instead. [Here is why you should not post your code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15366635)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last comma, just after **social integer**

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE personalinfo (
        name text,
        lastname text,
        age integer,
        social integer
        )""")
```